# timer is not working well with TimeSpan from milliseconds

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, timer

I am working on my app for Windows Phone 8 
and i created a DispatcherTimer

```
DispatcherTimer Timer= new DispatcherTimer();
 private int TimePass;
 public TapFast()
    {
        TimePass = 0;
        Timer.Tick += new EventHandler(TimePassTick);
        Timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1);
        InitializeComponent();
    }

 public void TimePassTick(Object sender, EventArgs args)
    {

         TimePass++;

         TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(TimePass);
         string answer = string.Format("{0:D2}h:{1:D2}m:{2:D2}s:{3:D4}ms",
                                 t.Hours,
                                 t.Minutes,
                                 t.Seconds,
                                 t.Milliseconds);


         time.Text = answer;
     }
```

When i start the timer , i don't get the right result in the TextBlock

1 second = 1000 milliseconds

I must see a value of **0** increases to **1000** in **1** second
but it takes like 18-20 seconds to get to 1000ms

what is the problem ?

Comment: From MSDN: Timers are not guaranteed to execute exactly when the time interval occurs, but they are guaranteed to not execute before the time interval occurs. This is because DispatcherTimer operations are placed on the Dispatcher queue like other operations. When the DispatcherTimer operation executes is dependent on the other jobs in the queue and their priorities.

Answer (score 1):

Windows and the associated APIs are not "real time". Your timer interval is so small that there's no way for Windows to service it on the schedule you're asking for.

With non-real-time OS and APIs, you can't assume that the timer is actually signaled on exactly the interval you asked for. You need to keep track of the actual time yourself (e.g. using the `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` class) and accommodate variations you experience.

Comment: do you have an example how to use that class?

Comment: Did you look at the documentation on MSDN? What about the example they provide do you not understand? What other details _specifically_ do you need help with? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx